# How to locate the code for a text box in a Windows Form application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, debugging

I have the code for a Windows Form application which is written in C#. There's a single-line text box as an input field in this application. I want to change this text box to allow taking multiple lines as input. This box has a fixed width and as soon as the user inputs a string longer than the width, the rest of the input should be moved to the next line. I don't know what kind of code change will be needed for this but first I need to be able to find out where the code this input textbox is.

I have never worked with Windows Form apps before this so don't know how I can do this. I tried to start the application with the debugger in Visual Studio and I see some options like "Go to Live Visual Tree", "Show in XAML Live Preview", "Select Element", "Display Layout Adorners" and "Track Focussed Element". I think I will have to use some of these but I couldn't find anything helpful by googling.

Comment: In the Solution Explorer, find the Form or User Control in question, right click it and select View Code.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT Noneof the answers here worked for me.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT I will try to update the question with some more details.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select "that" textbox, and press F4. This will open Properties Window.
2. From the property window, change the "Multiline" property to True.
3. This will allow your textbox to have multiline input at runtime.

Comment: I started the application with the debugger, selected the text box and pressed F4, Nothing happened.

Comment: @StupidMan Select the textbox in the WinForms designer in design-mode, not when the application is running.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change this text box to allow taking multiple lines as input, you can refer to the following setps:
First right-click on the textbox and choose Properties.
[image]

Then change Multiline to True.
[image]

Finally change WordWrap to True. If the user's input is longer than the width of the textbox, the rest of the input will be moved to the next line.
[image]